# php form html button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I had a website where you could select a site that you want to be redirected to from a dropdown menu & then click a button to be redirected to it.

As smart as i am i got a virus on my pc, & restored from an old backup. Short story; the site no longer works.. here is the code:

HTML:

```
   <form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="process.php">
       <select name="taskOption" id="taskOption2">
        <option value="Select">Please select a site</option>
        <option value="http://www.Itslearning.com">Itslearning</option>
        <option value="http://www.NDLA.no">NDLA</option>
       </select>
    </form>

    <button onclick="FormSubmit()" class="button button1 button1:hover">Take me there</button>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$taskOption $_POST["taskOption"];
if ($taskOption) {
    header("Location: $taskOption");

}
else {
   echo "Venligst velg en side.";
   exit;
}



?>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    function FormSubmit() {
document.form1.submit();
}
```

Comment: quite easy to abuse that particular service unfortunately - potentially you could end up as the point of origin for thousands of malicious/fake requests. If the URLS you use in the select menu are from the db then a unique id or hash to denote the url rather than the actual url would be better ( so long as the id/hash is verified in `process.php` and translated into the correct url )

Comment: not quite sure how that would happen, but this is just for a school project so i doubt anyone will abuse it.. thanks for letting me know though :) And by the way, what should i have used instead?

Comment: You may want to check if your posted data (`$_POST`) are set first, before trying to check if it fits your particular value

Comment: I could target the form on your site but substitute whatever url I wanted - `process.php` would receive the POST request and send a request to the URL I chose to send, thus the traffic originates from your site.

Comment: oh, i see.. thanks for the warning.. how would you do it then? would you have used another language or something?

Comment: as I mentioned above, if you store the urls in a database, add a column to the table that stores the urls ( I'd prefer a varchar column to store a random hash ) and use the hash in the select menu as the value. `process.php` would receive that value in the POST request and could determine if it was a legitimate url from your db and not a random url chosen by a spammer

Answer (score 2):

What is the error you receive? At least one error is in your PHP file:

```
<?php
$taskOption = $_POST["taskOption"];
if ($taskOption) {
    header("Location: $taskOption");
} else {
   echo "Venligst velg en side.";
   exit;
}
?>
```

Note the "=" on the second line.

Comment: I tested it with the "=", and it worked :) The error said ""sitename" is currenly unable to handle your request" or something like that. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, looks like you're missing an assignment operator (=) in your PHP.

It should look like this:

```
<?php
$taskOption = $_POST["taskOption"];
if ($taskOption) {
    header("Location: $taskOption");

}
else {
   echo "Venligst velg en side.";
   exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: It seems like that solved it :D I feel really stupid now, but thank you :)

Comment: No worries. You might want to set up a linter with your code editor so that small syntax errors like this get highlighted :)

Comment: im kinda new to coding, but ill try do add this "linter". what text editor would you reccomend by the way? i currently use "Atom":.

Comment: I've not used Atom but I hear good things. Try [this](https://atom.io/packages/linter-php). If that doesn't help, I personally use Sublime and I know a lot of other Devs do so you'll easily be able to get help setting up extensions and things.

Answer (score 1):

```
Simple table to store urls:

create table `urls` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `url` varchar(255) not null default '0',
    `hash` varchar(16) not null default '0',
    `hits` smallint(5) unsigned not null default '0',
    primary key (`id`),
    unique index `hash` (`hash`)
)
engine=innodb;



Gives this structure:

+-------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| url   | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| hash  | varchar(16)          | NO   | UNI | 0       |                |
| hits  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+



Populated with dummy urls & unique hashes:

+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------+
| id | url                            | hash             | hits |
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------+
|  1 | http://www.example.com/page/1  | 53abc566010de29a |   45 |
|  2 | http://www.example.com/page/2  | 8664d7fca34963d2 |   83 |
|  3 | http://www.example.com/page/3  | fe06dca79d3d0415 |   49 |
|  4 | http://www.example.com/page/4  | 3913aaaef701ecad |   35 |
|  5 | http://www.example.com/page/5  | eb2eddc3ca2406c3 |   93 |
|  6 | http://www.example.com/page/6  | acc809b96c6a42d9 |   50 |
|  7 | http://www.example.com/page/7  | 63a4e53b1b374fcb |   90 |
|  8 | http://www.example.com/page/8  | d9c13a146fc7c69a |   18 |
|  9 | http://www.example.com/page/9  | eaa944c7e9a4ef7c |   76 |
| 10 | http://www.example.com/page/10 | 59f9d294a29601c9 |   13 |
+----+--------------------------------+------------------+------+



In the php page that displays the menu for the user to choose from

<?php

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'xxx';
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    $sql='select * from `urls` order by `id`;';
    $result=$db->query( $sql );

    if( $result ){

        $html=array();
        $html[]="<form name='launcher' method='post' action='process.php'>";
        $html[]="<select name='taskOption'>";   

        while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ){
            $html[]="<option value='{$rs->hash}'>{$rs->url}";
        }

        $result->close();
        $db->close();

        $html[]="</select>";
        $html[]="<input type='submit' value='Go' />";
        $html[]="</form>";

        echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
    }


?>





<?php
    /* process.php */

    /*

        Rather than sending the actual URL via POST we only send a hash
        which is then used in the sql to find the real url from the database.

    */

    $errors=array();
    $url=false;

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['taskOption'] ) ){

        /* rudimentary sanitisation of the string */
        $hash = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'taskOption', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        /* db credentials */
        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'xxx';
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
        $dbname =   'xxx';
        $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

        /* construct statement to find the url */
        $sql='select `url` from `urls` where `hash`=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        if( $stmt ){

            /* bind the variable - hash */
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $hash );
            $result=$stmt->execute();

            /* */
            if( $result ){
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $url );
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->free_result();

                if( !$url ) $errors[]='Unable to locate url';

                $sql='update `urls` set `hits`=`hits`+1 where `hash`=?';
                $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

                if( $stmt ){
                    $stmt->bind_param('s',$hash);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->free_result();

                } else {
                    $errors[]='sql error updating hit count';
                }
            } else {
                $errors[]='No result found in database';
            }
        } else {
            $errors[]='sql error whilst preparing initial statement';
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $db->close();





        /* Redirect the user if all went well otherwise show an error message */
        if( empty( $errors ) ) exit( header("Location: $url") );
        else exit( "There were errors processing your request." );

    }

    /* only accept POST requests */
    exit( 'Bad foo - wrong method' );
?>
```

Comment: This is definitively more complicated than i want this site to be, but if i ever make another site with the same function this may come in handy :P thanks :)